# How Logical operators work with constant operand in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, reachability

I am working on project where I have the **checkInternet** method in one of my class for verifying internet availability. In that method I have following code:

For below code of line I am getting warning that, **"Using Logical && with constant operand"**
for this code of block **(flag && kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)**.

```
BOOL isavailable = NO;
Boolean success;
isavailable = success && (flag && kSCNetworkFlagsReachable) && !(flag & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired);
```

and as a solution xcode giving option that "Use & for bitwise operand" that's fine I do it like that and it removed my warning.
But I want know how it was working logical operators? and Why it's telling me to change to for bitwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [bitwise operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) `&` compares each individual pair of bits. The result will be non-null only if the left and right operands have at least one matching bit set to 1.

Example : 0100 AND 0010 → 0000 but 0110 AND 0010 → 0010.

This operator allows you to use a single integer value to store several booleans on different bits, then use a second value (known as a mask) to filter the bits.

`kSCNetworkFlagsReachable` is equal to `1<<1` (`2`). Thus, `flag & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable` is true only if the second least significant bit of `flag` is set to 1.

Using `&&` instead of `&` is a common mistake. The compiler will try to detect that mistake. In your example, `kSCNetworkFlagsReachable` is a constant value. As `kSCNetworkFlagsReachable` is constant and always true, testing whether `flag && kSCNetworkFlagsReachable` is true is the same as testing whether `flag` is true. Thus it is very unlikely that you really wanted to use a constant value in a logical operation. That's why the compiler emits the warning.

Answer (score 3):

`kSCNetworkFlagsReachable` is an integer while `BOOL` is `typedef short`. Using logical and (`&&`) would return `YES` if both of them are non-0 while using bitwise and (`&`) will return integer (non-0) if any of matching bits are 1.

Comment: Hey Thanks for prompt answering. Can you just elaborate it more, If I understand you answer correctly where you want to say that, because of  it returning YES, it was working fine with logical operators and while using bitwise its also returning same i.e(non-0).Please explain little more.

Answer (score 0):

in the condition first evaluation has to false means it will not check in logical operator(&&). but in does the bitwise operator(&).

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise operator `(&)` does bit by bit AND operation and returns the result as an int value. For example if you do a bitwise AND operation with `00110011` and `11111111` the result would be.

```
   00110011
&  11111111
===========
   00110011
```

On the other hand logical operator `(&&)` does a comparison. It returns `int 1` if both variables is not equal `0` returns `0` otherwise. That means:

```
   00110011 => 0x33 => 51  => (BOOL) true
&& 11111111 => 0xFF => 255 => (BOOL) true 
===========
   00000001 => 0x01 => 1   => (BOOL) true
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider refactoring that code into neated if/else statements. It will become verbose, yes, but one year from now, when you may have forgotten the somewhat-arbitrary precedence rules, your code will remain legible and self-evident...