# Using logical || with enum values

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, clang

I have an MPMoviePlayerController instance. I wish to check its playbackState property for one of a number of values. As such I do something like this:

```
if (moviePlayer.playbackState == (MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped ||
                                  MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying ||
                                  MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused)) {
    // ...
    // Perform some logic
    // ...
}
```

This works as expected but causes a compiler warning:

> Use of logical '||' with constant operand.

The compiler's fix is to use the bitwise `|` operator instead. Searching on Stack Overflow you will find a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190669/how-logical-operators-work-with-constant-operand-in-objective-c) of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333113/warning-about-using-logical-between-constant-in-iphone) suggesting the same thing. **BUT** using the bitwise OR really isn't what I need here.

`MPMoviePlaybackState` is declared in MPMoviePlayerController.h:

```
enum {
    MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped,
    MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying,
    MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused,
    MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted,
    MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward,
    MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward
};
typedef NSInteger MPMoviePlaybackState;
```

This isn't a bitmask (and nor would it make much sense for it to be so — the enumerated values are mutually exclusive modes, not flags to be combined). I really do want to use the logical `||`.

(In my particular case, with the underlying values being 0,1,2 the bitwise example might work but that's just a coincidence.)

How should I rephrase to avoid the warning or what `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored ...` can I use to silence the warning?

(Bonus points for pointing to a list of all such diagnostics — I cannot seem to locate one in the manual.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I suggest using a switch/case block with fall trough logic like that:

```
switch(moviePlayer.playbackState){
    case MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped: /* falls through */
    case MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying: /* falls through */
    case MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused:  /* falls through */
        // your stuff
}
```

This will result in the intended behaviour with as less code as possible. Enums are made for exact the switch case kind of business. And they are performance optimized more than "if" statements, becuase the CPU does not even have to test the values when reaching the code. The compiler calculates the correct ASM jump offset at that location. So its as fast as lighning :)

Comment: Downvoted because you didn't actually explain what was wrong with the OP's code (the misplacement of `||`), and for the red herring (which is incorrect anyway) about performance. And for the "u".

Comment: About performance, I'm right. Just tested it myself to make sure. Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/7GNkpny5 About `||`: You're missing the point. It's not just "not wise"; the OP's use of `||` was *strictly incorrect.*

Comment: Heh, "that's because you are using optimization." Welcome to the second half of the twentieth century. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement looks fine to me, although the "History" section is a bit notation-heavy. Common optimizations are discussed in the section titled "Optimized switch".

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, the `(enumval1 || enumval2 || ..)` is wrong. You can't use the `||` operator like this, but only with logical expressions.
The `|` operator works, because it's a simple bitwise OR, which will do job for you only and only if your enum members are different powers of 2 (e.g. 1, 2, 4, 8, ...).

It's connected with bitwise representation of numbers in binary, which , if the number if the power of 2, is like this: 2->10, 4->100, 8->1000 etc. So, for `2 | 8` it will be like `0010 | 1000 = 1010`, which isn't zero, and `if` statement will proceed.

The compiler warnings are fully right and helping at this point. Use the `switch(..)` or `if(..) else if(..)` statements, or make your enum like this:

```
enum yourEnum
{
  enumval1 = 1 << 0;
  enumval2 = 1 << 1;
  enumval3 = 1 << 2;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't know about the "obvious", the "wrong" or the "can't" here. Semantically (X||Y||Z) is exactly what I'm after. It's correct. And I am using it. Thank you explanation but I do understand bitwise representations. The enum in question is Apple's so unfortunately I cannot change it.

Comment: It's not about Apple. When you use the `||` operator, operands are casting to the boolean type. It becomes true/false logical operation, not bitwise.

Comment: Ah, yes — it's the casting. Thank you! You're right, it has nothing to do with the bitwise representation. @wilsteel's answer is the best.

Comment: Still can't see why his answer is the best. :) You had some misunderstanding of the basic point of logic operators in c++, why would presenting an example of using switch statement be the best answer?..

Comment: "Best": just that it captures the intent of my original (mistaken) code — I want to alternate the possible modes in the enum. Given the underlying representation I can't do that with `||` — silly error; IMO the switch is the clearest alternative — `if` statements with lots of clauses (often) being harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

why wouldn't you just do this?

```
if ((moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped) ||
    (moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) ||
    (moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused)) {
    // ...
    // Perform some logic
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Actually, with `-O3` the code will likely be identical... and it will use the x86's `bsrq` instruction to test set membership, rather than doing a simple `cmp`/`je`, in both cases. Personally, I'd go with the `if` for one or two cases, and the `switch` for five or more, with the OP's example falling into a gray area in the middle.